# Restarting Springboot Application via batch script

Tags: java, batch-file, spring-boot

I have a Springboot application which I need to restart upon returning some exit code(`System.exit(5)`) say. I know nothing about writing batch script.
Upon searching I found code which seems for a Java core Application.

```
@echo off

:start

java SpringBootApp %1
set exitcode=%ERRORLEVEL%
pause
if %exitcode% == "5" (goto :start)
```

Other methods were of using `jar` files, but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Please help!

Comment: 1. Use `"%~1"` rather than `%1`. 2. There's no need to assign `ERRORLEVEL` to `exitcode`. 3. Do the comparison like `if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 5 goto :start` to do true numeric comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion, could you provide a more descriptive answer upon where to place file, what exactly to write, It would be of great help, Thanks!